# How to display array into blade [Laravel 5]

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

In my modal I have finction `getMyGroups` like this:

```
foreach($groups as $group){
  $questions[] = array($group -> name => Question::where('group_id',$group-> group_id));
 }
  return $questions;
```

This will be returnet to the Controller:

```
if(is_numeric($id)){
  return view('project',array('groups' => $mygroups->getMyGroups($id)));  
}else{
  return redirect('home');
     }
```

So in blade I need to get:

This key `$group -> name` from first function in h1 tag and values into p tag, like this:

```
<h1> This is first key </h1>

<p>this is 1. value for first key</p>
<p>this is 2. value for first key</p>
<p>this is 3. value for first key</p>
...

<h1> This is second key </h1>

<p>this is 1. value for second key</p>
<p>this is 2. value for second key</p>
<p>this is 3. value for second key</p>
...
```

Array from $groups:

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    "key123" => Builder {#213 ▼
      #query: Builder {#218 ▶}
      #model: Question {#217 ▶}
      #eagerLoad: []
      #macros: []
      #onDelete: null
      #passthru: array:12 [▶]
    }
  ]
  1 => array:1 [▼
    "key2" => Builder {#215 ▼
      #query: Builder {#207 ▶}
      #model: Question {#208 ▶}
      #eagerLoad: []
      #macros: []
      #onDelete: null
      #passthru: array:12 [▶]
    }
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Blade has a [`@foreach()`](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures) which should get you started:

```
@foreach ($groups as $group => $name)
    <h1> This is {{ $name }} </h1>

    <p>this is ...</p>
@endforeach
```

You will need to adjust the markup depending on your array structure. Possible using a nested `@foreach` to display the paragraphs.

Comment: I get error: `htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: /home/client/public/resources/views/project.blade.php)`

Comment: Again, I don't know the structure of you're array, this is just an example. You'll need to adjust the output. If you post a `dd()` of `$groups` in your question, I will update the answer.